# Как преобразовать .doc в .html?

Tags: doc, php, html

Здравствуйте.

Каким образом можно преобразовать .doc файлы в обычный текст?

Наработки:

```
<?php
$fn = 'tmp/' . rand(1, 99999) . '.txt';
if (copy($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], $fn)) {
    $all = file($fn);
    $c   = count($all);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        echo $all[$i];
    }

    unlink($fn);
}    
?>
```

Comment: Хм.... Сохранить с другим разрешкием?

Comment: Неплохие наработки, я бы даже сказал, что почти готово.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну, ваши наработки тут врядли пригодятся. Есть [готовый класс](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse.html/package/388/download/targz/name/msfilesconverter-2001-11-19.tar.gz), который конвертит doc-файлы. Обращаю внимание на то, что нормально работает именно с файлами doc, а не docx. Во втором случае конвертирует, но сохраняет без расширения. Хотя "подрихтовать" класс можно, а именно строку:

```
$filename_path =  substr($filename,0,-4);
```

Вся проблема данного класса в том, что оно отсекает расширение у исходного файла doc, учитывая четыре символа: 3 символа расширения, плюс точка. Проверив расширение этого файла, можно изменять значение от "-4" до "-5" или же сделать по своему, например:

```
$filename_path =  substr($filename,0,-(strlen(array_pop(explode(".", $filename))) + 1));
```

Проверял - работает.

P.S. И еще почитайте статейку "[Текст любой ценой: DOCX и ODT](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69417/)". Тоже очень позновательно. Цитата из статьи:

> Итак, этой статьёй я открываю список
> публикаций о чтении текста из
> следующих типов файлов: DOC, DOCX,
> RTF, ODT и PDF — с помощью PHP без
> использования сторонних утилит.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.